# trouble understanding this EXISTS query

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, exists

Table `acc_account` sample data:

```
acc_id  acc_code  parent  name
------- --------- ------ ------
 1     | aaa     |  -1  |  A   |
 2     | bbb     |  CP  |  B   |
 3     | ccc     |  OP  |  C   |
 4     | ddd     |  -1  |  D   |
```

Columns `acc_code` and `parent` aren't equal right?

The table has 411 rows and there isn't even any record of `acc_code` that matches the `parent` column.

This query below however, returns 6 rows when it should be all 411 rows.
Anyone can explain?

Query (Returns 6 rows):

```
   SELECT *
    FROM acc_account a1
    WHERE not EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM acc_account
        WHERE acc_account.parent = a1.acc_code
   );
```

Comment: **`Postgresql` <> `SQL Server`**. Please tag correctly or write that you need code that should be portable.

Comment: the query works for both

Comment: Are there any `NULL`s in play here?

Comment: Apparently there are records where `parent` is equal to `acc_code` in some other record. You are not comparing within a record, but across the whole set.

Comment: no `NULL`s inside either columns

Comment: @HoneyBadger what do mean by across the whole set? I've been going crazy about this matter the whole day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you got the following set:

```
acc_id  acc_code  parent  name
------- --------- ------ ------
 1     | aaa     |  -1  |  A   |
 2     | bbb     |  CP  |  B   |
 3     | ccc     |  OP  |  C   |
 4     | ddd     |  -1  |  D   |
 5     | CP      |  -1  |  E   |
```

Your query would return the record with `acc_id` = 5, because `acc_code` = CP exists as `parent` in record with `acc_id` = 2.

In order to search within a record you could alter you query like:

```
SELECT *
FROM acc_account a1
WHERE not EXISTS (
                   SELECT *
                   FROM acc_account
                   WHERE acc_account.parent = a1.acc_code
                       AND acc_account.id = a1.id
                 );
```

Or much simpler:

```
SELECT *
FROM acc_account a1
WHERE a1.parent = a1.acc_code
```

**edit** I just noticed you are looking for `NOT exists`, so the logic described here is the other way around.

Comment: Just a small question, I kinda understand how it works now but when we `UPDATE` and `SET` `acc_code WHERE` `acc_code=parent` would it update `acc_id`=5 in your sample table?

Comment: No, if you just specify `WHERE acc_code=parent` it will only update records where `acc_code = parent` of that record. In my sample table that does not occur.

Comment: Thanks, so for clarity `WHERE acc_code=parent` would check across the whole set of records only within the `EXISTS` condition?

Comment: That's correct, unless you specify it should look within the same record as I've shown.

Comment: Thanks, I can finally not get crazy.

Comment: Glad I could help rid the world of at least some crazy :P